# How javascript object inheritance work?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, javascript-objects

I have following code

```
var createObj = function (prop1, prop2) {
   var obj = {
       prop1: prop1,
       prop2: prop2
   }
   Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop3", {
      get: function () {
          return this.prop1 + ' ' + this.prop2;
      },
      configurable: true
   });
   return obj;
}

var createSecObj = function () {
    var obj = createObj("prop1", "prop2");
    var prop3 = obj.prop3;

    Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop3", {
       get: function () {
           return prop3;
       }
    });
    return obj;
}
```

I am trying to learn how javascript inheritance work.

Lets say an object named myObj is created as

```
myObj = createSecObj();
```

Then value of myObj.prop3 is logged to the console as

```
console.log(myObj.prop3) // "prop1 prop2"
```

And then myObj.prop1 is changed as "blah" using

```
myObj.prop1 = "blah"
```

And again if the myObj.prop3 is logged to the console it results "prop1 prop2". and not "blah prop2".

```
 console.log(myObj.prop3) // results "prop1 prop2", expecting "blah prop2"
```

Looks like obj.prop3 still refer its parent object. what is the reason for this even it is redefined in child object. Could someone please explain this in detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Looks like `obj.prop3` still refer its parent object. what is the reason for this even it is redefined in child object.

The issue has nothing to do with inheritance. The issue is that you overwrote `prop3` with

```
var prop3 = obj.prop3; // var prop3 = "prop1 prop2";

Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop3", {
   get: function () {
       return prop3; // will always return "prop1 prop2"
   }
});
```

`obj.prop3` will always return the value of the **variable** `prop3`. The value of the variable `prop3` cannot be changed anymore throughout the application, and at the moment it was created, its value is `"prop1 prop2"`.

It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve here, so I can't really suggest a solution. If you want to get `"blah prop2"` then simply remove the above lines from your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) i want to re use the code createObj , prop3 without re writing it as return this.prop1 + ' ' + this.prop2; inside createSecObj.prop3 getter. Please consider this is for learning purpose. not for production level application:) just want to check how things can be done :) Please excuse me for my bad English.

Comment: If you simply want to refer to the inherited `prop3` property, you could write `return Object.getPrototypeOf(this).prop3;`, but there is no point in doing this. It seems you don't want to overwrite the property so don't do it.